# How can I make this variable generate a new random number on div refresh?

Tags: javascript, random

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
// Sets the variable randomNumber to a random number between 0 and 1 x 10,000

var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('#screen').load('screen.php');
}, (randomNumber));
// Refreshes #screen at an interval of randomNumber
```

I would like that every time the #screen div refreshes, a new random number is generated. As it is right now, the div refreshes only at the first random number set.

Comment: I would recommend setting a minimum refresh time as well ... an interval of 1 can have pretty destructive effects.

Comment: Will keep this in mind as well, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

```
function scheduleNextLoad() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#screen').load('screen.php');
        scheduleNextLoad();
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000));
}

scheduleNextLoad();
```

Comment: +1. It would also be good to not choose refresh times < 100 :)